# How to run jmeter from jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jmeter, devops

I am setting up jenkins job to run jmeter which is hosted in different host(jemter test setup is there and currently can be executed from terminal and need to setup jenkins job for same). SO far I have created a jenkins job and configured ssh-agent plugin and I am able to run "ssh host_name" command from my jenkins job and getting response. 
I am stuck and not sure how I can write shell script in my jenkins job to ssh and navigate to jmeter bin directory(apache-jmeter-4.0/bin/) and invoke jemeter test. Any help on this will be really appreciated.

Comment: I would say use some runner like ant. it gives you more options. http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-continuous-performance-testing-part2/

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should run your JMeter test on Jenkins directly, either on [Master](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines+on+Windows) node or on one of [slaves](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds). So you need to install Jenkins Slave agent software on the machine where JMeter lives and once done you will be able to run JMeter either via [`Execute shell` task](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Shells) or via [Groovy pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/).

This way you will also be able to get benefits from [Performance Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-jenkins-performance-plugin) which publishes test results trend to the project dashboard and also can mark builds as UNSTABLE or FAILED if response time or error rate is higher than defined thresholds.